# python pytorch use pretrained model

Tags: python, pytorch, artificial-intelligence

I trained a model using [this](https://github.com/clovaai/deep-text-recognition-benchmark) github repository. It's a CRNN[10] model and I want to use it now to make predictions. With what I've read, I need to excecute this:

```
model = TheModelClass(*args, **kwargs)
model.load_state_dict(torch.load(PATH))
model.eval()
```

To do that I need the model class of my network. How do I know what class I have? I tried `torchvision.models.crnn()` and `torchvision.models.crnn10()`, but both of these don't work. Can anyone tell me how I can load my model?

Comment: What is the error message? I suspect you would need to use the `Model`, inherited from `nn.Module` defined in their repository :
https://github.com/clovaai/deep-text-recognition-benchmark/blob/master/model.py

Answer (score 0):

The Model class is given in the above GitHub repository. To use your trained model weights you can do this.

1. Clone the above repo
2. create your test file inside the repo
3. Add this code to load the model

   from model import Model
   #create opt class with all these attributes: opt.imgH,opt.imgW,opt.num_fiducial, opt.input_channel,opt.output_channel,opt.hidden_size, opt.num_class,opt.batch_max_length,opt.Transformation,opt.FeatureExtraction,opt.SequenceModeling, opt.Prediction)
   model = Model(opt)
   model.load_state_dict(torch.load(PATH))
   model.eval()

Comment: What exactly should be in this opt class. I now have `class opt:
 def __init__(self):
  self.imgH
  self.imgW
  self.num_fiducial
  self.input_channel
  self.output_channel
  self.hidden_size
  self.num_class
  self.batch_max_length
  self.Transformation
  self.FeatureExtraction
  self.SequenceModeling
  self.Prediction` which gives me the following error: `in __init__
    self.stages = {'Trans': opt.Transformation, 'Feat': opt.FeatureExtraction,
AttributeError: type object 'opt' has no attribute 'Transformation'`. Should this class inherit from another class?

Comment: I moved the model.pth file to another directory so I could use it there, but now I realise, I need that as well, so that solves part of the problem, but now I'm left with this

Comment: The above class looks like it has all thi input arguments needed. Now use the same input arguments that you used while training to initialize the model.